# Freezing all but one positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

What's a good way to define a function `partial_k(f, k, args)` that takes an arbitrary function `f` as input (`f` takes `n` positional arguments), a value k, and a list of `n-1` values, and returns a new function that freezes all the arguments of `f` except the k-th argument?

For example:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return (a, b, c)

assert partial_k(f, 2, [0, 1])(10) == (0, 1, 10) # lambda x: (0, 1, x)
assert partial_k(f, 1, [0, 1])(10) == (0, 10, 1) # lambda x: (0, x, 1)
```

I could only find some very verbose ways of doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wrapper function and pass the arguments before and after `k`th item using slicing to the original function `f`:

```
def partial_k(f, k, seq):
    seq = tuple(seq)  # To handle any iterable
    def wrapper(x):
        return f(*(seq[:k] + (x,) + seq[k:]))
    return wrapper

print(partial_k(f, 2, [0, 1])(10))
print(partial_k(f, 1, [0, 1])(10))
```

**Output:**

```
(0, 1, 10)
(0, 10, 1)
```

[For Python 3.5+:](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448)

```
def partial_k(f, k, seq):
    def wrapper(x):
        return f(*seq[:k], x, *seq[k:])
    return wrapper
```

Comment: It's kind of amusing sitting on this page, watching you repeatedly make small edits. I suppose this is the whole: get your answer up quickly, then edit it repeatedly strategy in action. Btw, your comment "handle both lists and tuples" is technically correct but incomplete. It will actually handle any iterable.

Comment: @NirFriedman Yeah! SO provides a 5 minute edit window, looks like I missed it by few seconds. :-) You're right about the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use things from functools package to simplify further, but basically:

```
def make_partial(f, args, k):

    def func(x):
        new_args = args[:k] + [x] + args[k:]
        return f(*new_args)

    return func
```